# Lambda Duration using Cloud watch MetricFilter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am trying to create the metric filter for the Lambda duration so that if the lambda exceeds 5-sec duration it should create an alarm:

[Filter and pattern syntax - Amazon CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html)

```
REPORT RequestId: 12345 Duration: 280.00 ms Billed Duration: 280 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 98 MB Init Duration: 637.73 ms
```

I want to filter this value.

```
Duration: 280.00 ms
{ $.Duration >= 200.00 }
```

trying with this filter it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: There is already a `Duration` metric. Why do you need new one?

Comment: I need specifically Metrics Like { $.Duration >= 50000 Ms} but my search pattern not giving any results. My requirement is like Cloud Alarm need to be created if the Lambda duration take more than 5 seconds.

Comment: @Marcin the Regular duration Metric using the AWS/Lambda namespace where i cannnot make it to listen to 5, 10 or 30 seconds only 60 seconds or more i can set for alarm. So i am trying to filter the Duration using metric filter and create an alaram based on the metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{ $.Duration >= 200.00 }` is a `JSON` filter syntax, but you don't have logs in the `JSON` format - just plain text. In theory you can use [CloudWatch Logs Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html), but it seems to be an overkill.

As Marcin has mentioned in the comment: standard Lambda CloudWatch metrics offer `Duration` metric - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html - you can use it in the CloudWatch Alarm without any additional Lambda log processing.